# Python float formatting conundrum

Tags: python

I have a (simplistic) script :

```
length = int(input("Length ? "))
width = int(input("Width ? "))
area = int(length * width)
perimeter = int(2 * (length + width))
ratio = float(length/width)

print "The area is", area
print "and the perimeter", perimeter
print("for a ratio L/W of {0:.3f}".format(ratio))
```

For, e.g., length = 43 and width =17, I get

- area = 731 (which is OK),
- perimeter =120 (ditto),

but for the ratio, I get 2.000, although I should have 2.529

Where did I go wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you're using Python 2, the operator `/` between two integers always returns an integer. You want to cast one to `float` before doing the division.

Comment: TL;DR use `ratio = float(length)/float(width)`

Comment: @BhargavRao : you were right to mark it as duplicate. I found my answer. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem @ThG. The post was well framed so +1. :)